# How can I serialize and send a std::list over the network?

Tags: c++, stl

I need to send a dynamically sized list of data stored inside a std::list over a network connection. I would like to do this in one pass using serialization, rather than sending each element individually. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's boost::serialization, but whether it's viable or not depends on your requirements, does throughput matter for example?

Comment: Try Apache Thrift. It's kind of cute.

Comment: You'll still likely have to walk through the list one element at a time (depends on your list implementation I guess). You may still gain a little bit by "batching" the IO like you suggest, but I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 5):

[`boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) makes this fairly easy to do. It provides all of the mechanics you need for `std::list` for free, all you will need to do is add support to the type your list holds. (If it's a "standard" type this will already exist too)

Complete example (adapted from [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase)):

```
#include <list>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
// Provide an implementation of serialize for std::list
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

class foo
{
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
  {
    // This is the only thing you have to implement to serialize a std::list<foo>
    ar & value;
    // if we had more members here just & each of them with ar
  }
public:
  int value;
};

int main() {
  std::stringstream out;

  // setup a list
  std::list<foo> list;
  {
    const foo f = {-1};
    list.push_back(f);
  }

  // serialize into the stream
  {
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(out);
    oa << list;
  }

  // read the stream into a newlist
  std::list<foo> newlist;
  {
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(out);
    ia >> newlist;
  }

  std::cout << newlist.front().value << std::endl;
}
```

This "sends" and "receives" via a `std::stringstream`, but it should be fairly trivial to adapt this to send and receive via the network API of your choice.

Comment: Sadly boost::serialization is lackluster if you send small packets, and only really performs decently if you send very large payloads, otherwise the meta data will take up an unreasonable amount of space. boost::serialization is overall a poor choice if archive size is important, even if you use their binary variants.

Comment: I love `boost:serialization`, particularly how it unifies storing and retrieving with a single operation. But I don't find it clear how to check for errors.

Comment: @Ylisar `boost::serialization` is extensible. Essentially it's just concepts, and the actual serialization is on top of those concepts. The library comes with a custom text and binary implementation, as well as XML implementation. But you can extend the library with your own custom serialization frontend if you think you can do better than these.

Comment: The gist of it is, you can't. You can do some compile time checks, but it's impossible to verify the integrity of the archive without another layer added on top of it ( adding a CRC at the very beginning and verifying the data before deserializing ). You can insert "sentinels", where you serialize a constant and then confirm that you get the very same when deserializing. However, as boost::serialization requires symmetry this data needs to be deserialized in release builds as well.

Comment: @Ylisar - I was making the assumption that a `std::list` will contain a reasonable number of items and the "ease of use" factor dwarfed the "how fast will it be?" for the developer. (That criticism of boost WRT "packet" size vs payload size would also be true of any XML based system that is well-formed+valid).

Comment: @wilhelmtell - you check for errors either via catching an exception (during the deserialize operation) or on the transport layer itself.

Comment: @wilhelmtell It's extensible, but certain aspects of it can't be altered. For example you pay at the very minimum 128 bytes ( probably more ), per exported type that's serialized to your archive, this is added to the header as meta data. As you need to retrieve the whole archive before you can deserialize, you'll need to transfer this meta data for every packet you send over the network.

Comment: @Ylisar `out.str().size()` is 58 with the example code I posted.

Comment: @Ylisar no, there's absolutely no minimum. Well technically there is, zero. `boost::serialization` is a bunch of concepts that say nothing about the actual serialization itself. `oarchive`, `iarchive` and friends do, but they're the extensions.

Comment: Look at the `serialize()` function. It's a template, and `Archive` is a concept.

Comment: @wilhelmtell The 128 bytes you pay for each type that's "exported" in the boost::serialization sense, that is, each type you want to be able to serialize through a base pointer ( so you pretty much want to export all types with a vtable ). This can't be altered ( well, unless you want to go in & modify the boost source ). In this trivial example I'd say 58 bytes is very hefty for list length + 1 int.

Comment: @Ylisar - it's 58 bytes for a `foo` which contains an int. At around 100 `foo`s that starts to look quite small though, of the same magnitude as the headers from TCP and IP.

Comment: @awoodland Yeah, I absolutely think it's a great option for some use cases, it just so happens I've ventured down the boost::serialization route before and was quite dissatisfied for our use case. We're a games studio, so for multiplayer we absolutely must use UDP. Optimal UDP packet size is around 1500 bytes, so keeping size down is essential.

Comment: @Ylisar - by chance I found http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#classinfo today - it looks like you can turn all the overhead off for cases where it matters! (Looks very handy, although I've not actually tried it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Use [xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) to convert to/from XML and send/receive it.