# How can I serialize and send a std::list in JSOn string over network?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, serialization, boost

I am trying to send a list of data which is inside **std::list** container over a network. Instead of sending each element of list individually i am trying to send it in one go. For this purpose I am using **boost::serialization**. I compile using following:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp DBAccess11.cpp -lsqlite3 -lboost_serialization
```

I took help of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141617/how-can-i-serialize-and-send-a-stdlist-over-the-network) which is very similar to what i am seeking.

Although, based on example,I compiled my program successfully. But unfortunately I fail to see any serialised output .

Below is my **DBAccess1.h** file.

```
#ifndef DBAccess1_HH  
#define DBAccess1_HH

#include <iostream>  // I have deleted some header for sake of readability
#include <list>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

using namespace std;    
//================================//   
struct SiteCode
{
      int siteID;
      int siteCode;
  private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
      {
            ar & siteID;
            ar & siteCode;
      }
 };

inline ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, SiteCode &site)
{
    out << "(" << site.siteID << "," << site.siteCode << ")";
    return out;
}
//================================//

class sqliteDB {
    list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list;
public:
    list<SiteCode> GET_ALL_Site_Code();
    void printList();
};
#endif**
```

Below is the **DBAccess11.cpp** file where all the functions are defined

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <list>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include "DBAccess1.h"

list<SiteCode> sqliteDB::GET_ALL_Site_Code()
{
        sqlite3 *db;
        const char *sql;
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;

        int rc = sqlite3_open("/path/to/database.db", &db);
        sql = "SELECT * FROM SiteCode;";       
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

    while(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            int A  = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
            int B = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);

            SiteCode info;
            info.siteID = A;
            info.siteCode = B;              

            cout<<"Preparing to push data into List"<<endl;
            Site_Code_list.push_back(info);
            cout<<"Data was pushed successfully"<<endl;

            std::stringstream out;

            // serialize into the stream
            {
                boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(out);
                oa << Site_Code_list;
//line-84>>>    cout<< oa << endl;
            }
        }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return Site_Code_list;
}
//====================================================//
void sqliteDB::printList()
{
     int s = Site_Code_list.size();
     cout << "The size of List is :" << s << endl;
     for( list<SiteCode> :: iterator it = Site_Code_list.begin(); it !=  Site_Code_list.end(); it++)     
     cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Below is **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include "DBAccess1.h"

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    sqliteDB object1;
    object1.GET_ALL_Site_Code();
    object1.printList();
    cout << "\n\nAll the statement were executed properly\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs perfectly if **LINE-84** of **DBAccess11.cpp** is not included. But i fail to see the serialised output.

The output without LINE-84 is as follows:

```
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
The size of List is :10
(7,786) (8,78) (9,785) (10,998) (11,656) (13,23) (14,7) (15,74) (16,954) (17,752)
```

when i try to **cout << oa** it shows me hundreds of error. The very first error is as follows.

```
DBAccess11.cpp: In member function ‘std::list<SiteCode> sqliteDB::GET_ALL_Site_Code()’:
DBAccess11.cpp:81:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘boost::archive::binary_oarchive’)
    cout << oa << endl;
            ^
```

This I know is operator overloading problem. But, All I want is to see the serialised data that will go on network. How do I do this ? kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to output to `cout` the `out` instance of the `std::stringstream` class and not the `oa` instance, i.e.

```
std::stringstream out;

            // serialize into the stream
            {
                boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(out);
                oa << Site_Code_list;
//line-84>>>    cout<< oa << endl;
            }
cout << out.str() << endl;
```

Please note, that the `oa` variable has the `binary_oarchive` type, i.e. binary type and the output will be no readable. To see something useful is necessary to use either `boost::archive::xml_oarchive` or `boost::archive::text_oarchive` types.

Comment: @megabyte1024- I tried your suggestion with some of my own changes and now I can see the output :). But now I want this data in JSON String format. I knw I will need to use ptree.hpp and json_parser.hpp. But if I use them then do I still need to use the  boost::archive::text_oarchive ? or Do I use just boost/ptree.hpp and boost/json_parser only ?

Comment: @K.K, I am not aware either the Boost property tree is able to work with the Boost archives (boost::archive::text_oarchive, etc). But I am assume that it does not. I see two opportunities to convert JSON data to a objects' structure using Boost. 1. To use the Boost property tree plus an adapter which converts a property tree to the required object structure. 2. To use the Boost Serialization plus to write a archive class which handles JSON data, in similar way as xml_oarchive and xml_oarchive handle XML data. Also is possible to use any other library which parses JSON data.